# EsLint Comma-Style for Function-Call

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am struggling with what I thought should be solved by the eslint - `comma-style` - Rule.

I want to prevent cases like this:

```
someFunction({}
  , "someString",
  [1, 2],
  "someOtherString")
```

where there is a line-break right **before** the comma in the second line.

Ideally, the sample should look more like this:

```
someFunction({}, 
  "someString",
  [1, 2],
  "someOtherString")
```

Where the comma is moved to the end of the first line with the line-break **after** the comma.

I thought that the rule `"comma-style": ["error"]` should fix it but it only applies for

> "a list of things separated by commas"

[Source: eslint.org](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/comma-style)

Is there some rule that does essentially the same as `comma-style`, but for Function-Calls?

Note: I am not after `"function-call-argument-newline": ["error", "never"]` as this would only solve the problem by preventing me from using line-breaks in function-calls altogether.